# What is the difference between these two "instruments" ICBIT charts

Tags: exchanges, exchange-rate

Sorry for the vague question, I will improve it once I get an answer...

In the picture bellow I marked two "Instruments" that are being used for trading on ICBIT. I don't understand what the difference is and why the value of one is so much higher than the other.

[image]

Any help understanding what that means would be great

Answer (score 1):

The number after the BTC/USD is the settlement date of that particular futures contract.

You can find a list of all ICBIT futures in this [page](https://icbit.se/futures), and clicking on one will show you all the details, for example: [BTC/USD-12.13](https://icbit.se/BUZ3)

As for why the prices are different, it's somewhat outside the scope of a Bitcoin discussion. I really suggest you read up on [Futures Contracts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_contract). Make sure to fully understand the nature of Futures trading before investing in it.